# MSI UAC always opens behind window

Tags: windows-7, uac, windows-installer

When installing MSI packages, the UAC prompt *always* appears *behind* the MSI installer window. This does not happen for any other scenarios (EXE installers, other programs, etc), just MSI packages.

This is a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

What gives?